How to know the maximum virtual memory of binary program after I run it?
When I want the maximum resident set size, I use /usr/bin/time
like
gcc -o foo foo.c
/usr/bin/time -f "%M" ./foo

I want to know the maximum total memory usage, including virtual memory.
Any packages or tricks?

Do you really mean the size of the virtual memory? Because that's going to be huge – 2⁵² or 2⁶⁴ bytes or something similar, and completely independent from what your program is or does. Or do you mean the sum of all the sizes of mappings into that virtual memory space, whether they were ever backed by physical memory or not, or mapped device memory, or some doubly-mapped shared memory or mmap'ed files? That seems like a pretty useless number, too, because it conflates so many things.

I want to know all of the variables and arrays sizes declared whether as global variables, in the stack memory, or in the heap memory. whether the program has used it or not.

that size doesn't exist; your compiler is free to omit variables you don't use, and it's free to merge constants that are identical, and especially, stack space formerly used by a variable that went out of life is instantly reused by the next variable that needs stack space. So, what you're looking for doesn't exist.

I see, but how they calculate the memory usage in online judges like codeforces?

that is going to be a much restricted environment, abnormally configured compilers, and also, plain wrong?  I'm sure they state that somewhere in their rules. Or they just count the resident set size, which would make most sense to me.
